# Vim Folding if line starts with two dashes for Todo Lists

Tags: vim

I want to experiment and find out if I can create a todo list with vim.

My structure looks like

```
November 2019
    Week 1
        Monday
        Tuesday
        Wednesday
        Thursday
        Friday
        Saturday
    Week 2
        Monday
        Tuesday
        Wednesday
        Thursday
        Friday
        Saturday
    Week 3
        Monday
        Tuesday
        Wednesday
        Thursday
        Friday
        Saturday
    Week 4
        Monday
        Tuesday
        Wednesday
        Thursday
        Friday
        Saturday
```

This structure is for every month the same and all indent based. I want vim to automatically fold the line and everything below the line that has a bigger indent that itself when it starts with two dashes.

For example, I have the structure

```
Week 2
    --Monday
        task 1
        task 2
        task 3
    Tuesday
    Wednesday
    Thursday
    Friday
    Saturday
```

So when if my current day is Tuesday I want to add two dashes to Monday since Monday is the past and mark as completed. If I have undone tasks I move them to Tuesday before.

To generalize the question.

Everything that starts with 2 dashes should be folded (also the same line) and all other lines that have a bigger indent than the current line.

Hope the question is clear, It would be great to get a solution or at least some inspiration for a solution.

Another alternative good be to use manual-folding with mkview and loadview to make vim remember the foldings but here I have the issue that he never folds the same line (Jaja it has its reasons for it). So question is, how to change it?

When I use foldmethod=manual (default) and execute za working in my todo he folds everything with the same indent. how to indent the same line and everything with a bigger indent as the same line?

Comment: `foldmethod=indent` could help.

Comment: it could but it does not fold the current line